# interpolate equally spaced points

Tags: python, parameters, interpolation

I am trying to use python to interpolate but I am having some troubles.
I have a given set of points in 3D space that form a curve. I do not know the analytic equation of the curve. I need to interpolate some points on that curve that are equally spaced on the curve.
Does anyone have any suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

What [kind](http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/interpolation/) of interpolation best suits?

If linear is all that's required, you can use the formula...

```
a * (1 - m) + b * m
```

Where `a` is the start, `b` is the finish and `m` is the magnitude between the points between `0` and `1`.

I wrote a [tool](https://rawgithub.com/alexanderdickson/interpolation-methods/master/index.html) where you can visualise different interpolation methods. Choose the one you prefer (note that some interpolate more than 2 points) and check the source code (should be simple enough to translate the JavaScript to Python) to see how it's accomplished.

Comment: thanks!
I don't think that linear interpolation will work because the curve has a rather arbitrary shape. where can I get the source code?
does anyone have any other suggestions?

Comment: @user2798905 Given it's JavaScript, you can view the page's source. Alternatively, [here is the repo](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/interpolation-methods).